# Sass with compas, selecting all divs with x class before hyphen

Tags: sass

I am using Sass and currently selecting my divs via:

```
[class*='inner-']{
  padding: $pad;
}
```

But i have two variants of this div which are: `-left`, `-right` but i wanted to see if there was a better way rather than doing individual style blocks for each one, if i could merge it into one block.

My variants have a slight variation on the padding.

So something like:

```
[class*='inner-']{
      padding: $pad;
      -left{
       atttribute
      }
      -right{
      attribute
      }
    }
```

I might be over thinking this and making it pointlessly complex, but it's helping me learn lots so if anyone can shed some light on the best solution I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I've understood what you need properly, but I think you making it too complex.

Nice and simple solution:

```
%inner {
   padding: somepadding;
}

.inner-left {
   @extend %inner;
   some other: attributes for left;
}

.inner-right {
   @extend %inner;
   some other: attributes for right;
}
```

We use placeholder (%inner), it's like a silent class, won't be outputed until called. Then extend it to those two classes. Nice, clean and maintainable solution.

Comment: ahh brilliant, this is exactly what i wanted :)